# Does RIP send the whole routing table in a Triggered Update?

Tags: routing, rip

I'm new to network engineering. Currently I'm studying a few routing protocols.

However, when I'm studying RIP. There is a small thing that is bothering me. I wasn't sure if RIP **sends all** its routing table to its neighbors or just **sends downed route** with metric of 16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, you should check the RFC ([RFC 2453, RIP Version 2, Section 3.10.1, Triggered Updates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2453#section-3.10.1)):

> **3.10.1 Triggered Updates**
>
> Triggered updates require special handling for two reasons.  First,
> experience shows that triggered updates can cause excessive load on
> networks with limited capacity or networks with many routers on them.
> Therefore, the protocol requires that implementors include provisions
> to limit the frequency of triggered updates.  After a triggered update
> is sent, a timer should be set for a random interval between 1 and 5
> seconds.  If other changes that would trigger updates occur before the
> timer expires, a single update is triggered when the timer expires.
> The timer is then reset to another random value between 1 and 5
> seconds.  A triggered update should be suppressed if a regular update
> is due by the time the triggered update would be sent.
>
> ***Second, triggered updates do not need to include the entire routing table.***  In principle, only those routes which have changed need to
> be included. Therefore, messages generated as part of a triggered
> update must include at least those routes that have their route change
> flag set.  They may include additional routes, at the discretion of
> the implementor; however, ***sending complete routing updates is strongly
> discouraged***.  When a triggered update is processed, messages should be
> generated for every directly-connected network.  Split Horizon
> processing is done when generating triggered updates as well as normal
> updates (see section 3.9).  If, after Split Horizon processing for a
> given network, a changed route will appear unchanged on that network
> (e.g., it appears with an infinite metric), the route need not be
> sent.  If no routes need be sent on that network, the update may be
> omitted.  Once all of the triggered updates have been generated, the
> route change flags should be cleared.